# Android: new permissions added behind my back after library updates

Tags: android, android-permissions

When I uploaded a new version of my app to the Developer Console for uploading to the Play Store, the dialog that pops up with an analysis of the apk told me that I had added two new permissions since the last version:

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

AFAIK I've done nothing in my code to add these permissions; certainly there is nothing in 'AndroidManifest.xml'.  I have no interest or need to read and write to external storage.  I have updated Android Studio and various required plugins since I last published a new version (I usually do this each time I'm notified that there are updates).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the new permissions came from your libraries, that you are using. If you have updated the Android Studio the libraries can changed too. Check [this article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html).

According to the article the final manifest file is merged from your own and from the libraries' ones, you can see it at `app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting article, thanks.  I do have the following dependency in my `build.gradle` file: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'` and I also recall having to push up the version number of this dependency after a recent update because there were build errors if I did not.  So maybe the new permissions come from there?

Comment: yes, I think so, you can check the final manifest, I've modified my answer! :)

Comment: @drmrbrewer do you have any other questions or I did answer all of them?

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with libraries including manifest with your application and its being merged with your application, adding permissions(as Bendaf said). One thing you can do is take your APK and decompile it and check your code for the permission.

Comment: you can also check app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml for permissions, it's in the article I have linked.

Comment: @bendaf had no idea you can do that :) I assume its the merged manifest?